# How are the enemies in Dragon League selected?

Tags: dragon-city

How are the human opponents for the fight in Dragon League selected? I've thought they are from the same league as I, but it's not very probable. Usually most of them are far weaker then I - about half of them has dragons level 10, for example, while mine are 15. A few are tough, but in the last leagues one opponent was always extremally tough - with 10 levels above me, very strong dragons. It's impossible those weak guys have beaten him.

Now one opponent is level 50 (mine is 25) and has dragons of level 20, and he is blocking me for weeks that I would need to get my dragons to such high level :( I suspect it's done on purpose to block players from getting gems for free....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the league is chosen randomly. The players within your league will have completed the amount of leagues you have completed. For example, you are on Dragon League 15. All your other opponents will only have completed 15 leagues (first one is Dragon League 0).

***Changes in Opponents***: Every six hours, if a user in your league has completed his/her league, that user will move up to the next league and another ***valid*** user will take that user's place. This can only apply to people you ***haven't*** defeated.

***Changing Leagues***: You can change the people in your league (the league number won't change, just the users) but will cost you one combat. Usually, only use it if most or all the other users are too powerful for you. Wait for a while to see for new user updates and if necessary, change the users. All users will change, defeated or not.

***League Level/Number***: This will match you will opponents within this league's number/level. It will be equal to the number of leagues you have successfully won by defeating everyone else. Opponents' levels and dragon levels will not be a factor.

I hope this helps you!